# Why do I get IDX20803 error after upgrading to IdentityModel v7 from v6?

Tags: c#, jwt, identitymodel

After upgrading `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to `7.0.0`, I get this error:

> IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://example.com/realms/Development/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. => Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.JsonConvert

Before the update, my package references were:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.32.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.32.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.3" />
```

After the update, my package references are now:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.3" />
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build.  Did you make same changes in client?  The serializer in the client has to be compatible with the deserializer in server.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

TLDR: add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.0" />`

---

Based on the [release notes](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/IdentityModel-7x#serialization-issues), between v6 and v7 of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`, the JSON serialiser/deserialiser has been changed from Newtonsoft Json.NET to `System.Text.Json`.

It has 2 implicit dependencies:

- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` (that you've made explicit in this case)
- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens`

[As defined](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/7.0.0#dependencies-body-tab), IdentityModel v7.0.0 also upgrades these implicit dependencies to their corresponding v7.0.0 - as expected & good so far.

The issue isn't with the upgraded packages but instead, highlights a problem with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package, which would be used alongside.

This package has an implicit dependency on `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect`.

However, the latest `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` v7.0.11 package incorrectly still [states](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/7.0.11#dependencies-body-tab) that `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` v6.15.1 is valid.

This is wrong in this case, as v6.15.1 isn't compatible with Identity Model 7 & its implicit dependencies.

---

The solution is making the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` dependency explicit and specifying [v7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect/7.0.0#readme-body-tab) in your project, to override the implicit v6 package - fixing the dependency version mismatch.

This should be a temporary fix until Microsoft hopefully fix this in their upcoming package updates.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.0" />
```

---

This is the most minimal set of packages that fix this issue:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: At 7.2 still not fixed

Comment: 7.0.0 is Vulnerable
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-59j7-ghrg-fj52

Comment: @traveler3468 Not for the package override (`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect`); the other packages can/should be upgraded as normal - are the newer versions of the other libraries incompatible with the override?

Comment: @ZorgoZ 7.2 didnt work for me unless I had Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI Updated

Comment: @traveler3468 That package isn't listed in the question but thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @ErmiyaEskandary , was struggling to find resolution of this issue.