# JWT broke after upgrading to version 7 of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm using JWT for my website's login.

This is the code I use in my `Startup.cs`:

```
    public static void AddIdentity(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
        {
            jwtOptions.Authority = @$"{ApiConfig.GetSetting("KeycloakUrl").Trim('/')}/realms/{ApiConfig.GetSetting("Realm")}";
            jwtOptions.Audience = "account";
            jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                {
                    c.NoResult();

                    Logger.LogException(c.Exception);

                    c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    if (ApiConfig.IsDeveloping)
                    {
                        return c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString());
                    }
                    return c.Response.WriteAsync("An error occured processing your authentication.");
                },
                OnTokenValidated = c =>
                {
                    if (c.Principal.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                    {
                        c.HttpContext.Items["IsSuperAdmin"] = true;
                    }
                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            if (IsSecurityEnabled())
            {
                if (ApiConfig.Role.IsSomething())
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("HasRole", policy => policy.RequireRole(ApiConfig.Role));
                }
                else
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("HasRole", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(x => x.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                options.AddPolicy("HasRole", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(x => true));
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that after upgrading `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to `7.0.0` now I get this error:

> IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://accounts.example.com/realms/SampleRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

I can't find where the problem is. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Upgraded from which version? To clarify, that's the only change you made? If you navigate to `https://accounts.example.com/realms/SampleRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration` manually, do you see a discovery document being loaded?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, from `6.32.3`. And that's the only change I have made. And yes, when I go there, I see a JSON being loaded.

Comment: Thank you - can you share the full list of packages you have installed (`PackageReference`) and the exact version of .NET you're using?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, how does that solve the problem? I'm using the latest version of .NET Core. `7.0.401`.

Comment: Hasan, can you please try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77121911/4800344

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, worked like a charm. What causes that? How Microsoft has published a package versioned `7.0.0` that does not automatically load `7.0.0` of its dependency? That's so weird.

Comment: Glad to hear :) yes they indeed have a dependency version mismatch. I'm going to dig a bit deeper into it and update that answer or potentially propose to fix it upstream. For now, I'm going to vote to close this question as a dupe if OK (or feel free to delete) so that there's one answer. Thank you!